# c# .net build error due to strawberry shake graphql client error - "access to the path 'obj\\berry' is denied"

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, strawberry-graphql, strawberryshake

Recently I updated my visual studio to the latest version of 17.5.1 and my target sdk version is NET 7.0 SDK (v7.0.102). Now I have a build error stating that "access to the path 'obj\berry' is denied". Anyone got the same error and suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

No idea if this is still an issue for you or not. I just had the problem this morning & couldn't figure it out. Tried closing studio & reopening it "as an admin" & that resolved the issue. It looks like the v17.5.x releases have added extra security ‍♀️

Comment: I updated strawberry shake 12 to 13 and it removed the issue. Also able to get rid of auto generated models and few dependencies of strawberry shake.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem when using **v12** of StrawberryShake with later versions of VS2022. I can be worked around by adding the following line to a PropertyGroup in your .csproj file

```
<StrawberryShake_State>$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)berry</StrawberryShake_State>
```

This has been fixed in **v13**, and is no longer necessary.
I should mention there are however other issues in v13, that's not present in v12 with regards to the client. So I would urge you to have a look at the [Github Issues](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc+label%3A%22%F0%9F%8C%B6%EF%B8%8F+strawberry+shake%22) list before upgrading to fix this minor issue.